# Protect certain cells when saving data to excel using R

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I want to save my data frame to Excel and protect/ lock certain cells. The function `openxlsx::protectWorksheet()` protects the entire sheet, and I've found an answer that uses `protectWorksheet()` in combination with `addStyle()` to unprotect the rest of the cells in order to protect certain cells.

However, it doesn't work in my case since I need to protect cells like `data[c(1:3, 5:10, 100:105), c(3:10, 8:12, 300:408)]`. It's just too complicated to unprotect the rest of the cells. Is there a way to directly protect certain cells?

My code:

```
library(openxlsx)

# Create a data frame
my_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c("John", "Jane", "Mike"),
  Age = c(25, 30, 35),
  Salary = c(50000, 60000, 70000)
)

# Create a new workbook and add the data frame to it
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
writeData(wb, "Sheet1", my_data)

# Set cell protection for specific cells (e.g., Name column)
protectWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", rows = 2:(nrow(my_data) + 1), cols = 1, protect = TRUE)

# Save the workbook as an Excel file
saveWorkbook(wb, "my_data.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: AFAIK this is how excel works, it will protect all cells in the worksheet by default and you have to unprotect the ones you would like to be editable. So one would expect `openxlsx` to follow this logic.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with `openxlsx2`. (I picked the `data[ , ]` part from above as your cell reference. I apply an unlocked cell style for the entire worksheet using a column style and lock only the cells I want locked.

```r
library(openxlsx2)
# create a workbook
wb <- wb_workbook()$add_worksheet()

# create an unlocked cell style
s1 <- create_cell_style(locked = FALSE)
wb$add_style(s1, "s1")

# make this the default cell style for the entire worksheet
wb$worksheets[[1]]$cols_attr <- sprintf(
  "<col min=\"1\" max=\"16384\" width=\"8.83203125\" style=\"%s\"/>",
  wb$styles_mgr$get_xf_id("s1")
)

# locked cells from OP?
dims_list <- list(
  list(1:3, 3:10),
  list(5:10, 8:12),
  list(100:105, 300:408)
)
dims_list <- lapply(dims_list, function(x)rowcol_to_dims(x[[1]], x[[2]]))

# lock a few ranges and highlight these in red
for (dims in dims_list) {
  message("locking: ", dims)
  wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("red"))
  wb$add_cell_style(dims = dims, locked = TRUE)
}
#> locking: C1:J3
#> locking: H5:L10
#> locking: KN100:OR105

# protect the worksheet and the workbook
wb$protect_worksheet()
wb$protect()

if (interactive()) wb$open()
```